# clock_getres and clock_gettime

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to measure a part of my program with clock_getres and clock_gettime , with the CLOCK_MONOTONIC clock.

If I understand correctly,  clock_gettime gets me the time that passed by measuring some kind of external clock (not the cpu), and updates it in struct timespec instance which he gets reference to, as paramer.(i.e. it returns the result in nanoseconds resolution)

what I need to know is not the actual time, but the number of cycles the clock (CLOCK_MONOTONIC)has made.

how can i do that? It might be something to do with clock_getres but I couldn't understand how it works exactly.

does anyone know how to get the number of cycles?

Answer (score 1):

Clock_gettime gets you the elapsed time between the epoch (or some other fixed time in the past, depending on the specific implementation on your platform) and the current time on the selected clock (in your case CLOCK_MONOTONIC).

To measure how long a process takes, you need to call it twice and calculate the difference.   Something like:

```
int main()
{
    timespec start, finish;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start);

    //code you want to profile

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &finish);

    //calculate the difference between start and finish     

    return 0;
}
```

note, this will give you a time value, if you want to know the CPU cycles, then you'll have to use something like rdtsc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <intrin.h>

#pragma intrinsic(__rdtsc)

int main()
{
    unsigned __int64 i;
    i = __rdtsc();
    printf_s("%I64d ticks\n", i);
}
```

Comment: thanks but that's not what I asked. I don't understand how to get the number of cycles CLOCK_MONOTONIC did. or, what clock_getres does? does that give me that clock's frequency?

Comment: CLOCK_MONOTONIC doesn;t give you any information about cycles, it gives you clock information. Try rdtsc instead (in intrin.h). clock_getres simply tells you the resolution of the specified clock, which is dependent on your platform.

Comment: You probably don't want the number of cycles as most computers operate at variable speed nowadays (power saving feature). clock_getres simply gets the smallest time delta it is able to measure (so, in theory, this could very well be 1/frequency, in practice, I don't know and POSIX seems to be unclear about it)

Comment: Jo So - that's what I thought about 'clock_getres' . But as you said, they are unclear...

Comment: @Jo So, in the practice, Linux OS returns from `clock_getres()` either  1-10 milliseconds (depending on `CONFIG_HZ` value; for low-resolution clocks) or 1 nanosecond (for all [high-resolution kernel timers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/hrtimers.txt)).